# how to update table if values in another table are inserted

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
mysql> select * from Teams;  
+-----------+---------+  
| team_name | team_id |
+-----------+---------+  
| India     |       1 |  
| England   |       2 |  
| Germany   |       3 |  
| Italy     |       4 |  
| Spain     |       5 |  
| Belgium   |       6 |  
| Brazil    |       7 |  
| France    |       8 |  
+-----------+---------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)


 select * from Players where team_id=7 or team_id=8;
+-----------+----------------+------------+------+--------+--------+---------+
| player_id | player_name    | position   | age  | height | weight | team_id |
+-----------+----------------+------------+------+--------+--------+---------+
|       130 | Jefferson      | Goalkeeper |   25 |      6 |     90 |       7 |
|       131 | Dani Alves     | Defender   |   30 |      6 |     65 |       7 |
|       132 | David Luiz     | Defender   |   26 |      6 |     73 |       7 |
|       133 | Thiago Silva   | Defender   |   29 |      6 |     69 |       7 |
|       134 | Marcelo        | Defender   |   24 |      5 |     65 |       7 |
|       135 | Paulinho       | Midfielder |   27 |      6 |     68 |       7 |
|       136 | Ramires        | Midfielder |   25 |      6 |     59 |       7 |
|       137 | Oscar          | Midfielder |   21 |      5 |     61 |       7 |
|       138 | Lucas Moura    | Striker    |   19 |      5 |     62 |       7 |
|       139 | Neymar         | Striker    |   21 |      5 |     63 |       7 |
|       140 | Alex Pato      | Striker    |   25 |      6 |     69 |       7 |
|       150 | Hugo Lloris    | Goalkeeper |   28 |      6 |     75 |       8 |
|       151 | Mathiu Debuchy | Defender   |   25 |      6 |     70 |       8 |
|       152 | Philip Mexes   | Defender   |   34 |      6 |     73 |       8 |
|       153 | Younes Kaboul  | Defender   |   29 |      6 |     81 |       8 |
|       154 | Patrice Evra   | Defender   |   34 |      6 |     75 |       8 |
|       155 | Paul Pogba     | Midfielder |   21 |      6 |     68 |       8 |
|       156 | Samir Nasri    | Midfielder |   27 |      6 |     69 |       8 |
|       157 | Yohan Cabaye   | Midfielder |   26 |      6 |     64 |       8 |
|       158 | Frank Ribery   | Striker    |   28 |      5 |     63 |       8 |
|       159 | Oliver Giroud  | Striker    |   25 |      6 |     74 |       8 |
|       160 | Karim Benzema  | Striker    |   24 |      6 |     71 |       8 |
+-----------+----------------+------------+------+--------+--------+---------+
22 rows in set (0.00 sec)



mysql> select * from Matches where match_id=4;
+----------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| match_id | match_date | hometeam | awayteam | homescore | awayscore |
+----------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|        4 | 2014-06-28 |        7 |        8 |         0 |         0 |
+----------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

(hometeam,awayteam are foreign keys Teams.team_id)

```
mysql> select * from livescore;
+----------+-----------+----------+---------+
| score_no | player_id | match_id | team_id |
+----------+-----------+----------+---------+
|        1 |       155 |        4 |       8 |
+----------+-----------+----------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

`(player_id,match_id,team_id are foreign keys of Players,Matches,Teams)`
I have a `Players` table wherein I have all players info.

What I want is when a new row is inserted in `'livescore'` the `homescore,awayscore` should be increased accordingly. ie If the player belongs to `team_id=8` in `livescore` then the `awayscore` where `awayteam=8` must be increased `+1`.

Comment: maybe work for http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a little trick with that you can do it in one single Query using ON DUPLICATE KEY construct:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`field_a`, `field_b`, `field_c`)
VALUES('val_a', 'val_b', 'val_c')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `field_c` = `field_c` + 1;
```

The duplicated key will automatically used as WHERE when using "ON DUPLICATE KEY" so this is very comfortable.

Keep in mind that rowa or atleast one key you are trying to insert must be a primary key or unique index that denies duplicate entries so this construct will work.

Comment: Is it possible to update existing row instead of inserting a new one with above code.@Steini

Comment: For this you should consider creating a trigger as Pavel said in your comment. With a trigger you can give a table a predefined behaviour like when a field gets updated you can execute custom code such as inserting or updating into another table. However, are you sure that you want two score tables? Cant you create one column in the livescore table at once for each score type?